# Header set with Apache in multiple htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a site at directory /aaa/bbb/ccc/index.php

I have an htaccess on every directory "/aaa", another in "/aaa/bbb" and another in "/aaa/bbb/ccc".

In the htaccess located at /aaa I have this

```
Header set AAA ZZZ
```

In the htaccess located at /aaa/bbb and /aaa/bbb/ccc I have this

```
Header set AAA XXXXXXXX
```

When I open the website using my browser the header AAA has the value ZZZ. For some reason the other htaccess files are not overriding the value of AAA. But what is really amazing is that if I change the htaccess from /aaa/bbb and /aaa/bbb/ccc to the code below the header gets overrided! Why?

```
<FilesMatch "^.*$">

    Header set AAA XXXXXXXX

</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: The `Header` directives in the subdirectories .htaccess files _should_ override the parent. Is this a specific header or a _custom_ header? Can you just confirm that the `Header` directives are not inside any other containers? By placing this directive in a `<FilesMatch>` container you are likely changing the order of execution. `Files` and `FilesMatch` containers are processed late in the request, possibly after other directives in .htaccess are processed.

Comment: @w3d I would like you were correct but that's not the case... multiple HEADER directives in different htaccess on subdiretories does not override the top most htaccess file. If only overrides if I use <filesMatch>. Could please check what I am saying on your backend and see by yourserf this strange behaviour?

Comment: Well that's the thing, I did already double check this on my development server (Apache 2.2). Using the directive `Header set X-Test <value>` in the document root .htaccess file and a .htaccess file 2 subdirectories deep. .htaccess files in subdirectories _should_ override the parent and a `set` action _should_ "replace any previous header" - so the behaviour I experience appears to be consistent with the docs. So I'm wondering what is different on your system?

Comment: @w3d I really appreciate your kindness for testing this. Your results are exactly what I would like to expect on my Apache 2.4, maybe there is some bug on Aapche 2.4 and I should report it. Do you know where I should report it? Cause the test you did is exactly the same as I did, but with different results.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug and I reported it to Apache community at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58789

Comment: I have since tested this on Apache 2.4.7, but I am still unable to reproduce the behaviour you are experiencing. I see the same behaviour on Apache 2.4.7 as I do on Apache 2.2.9 - setting the header in the subdirectory's .htaccess file overwrites the parent (as expected). I notice from the bug report that you are using Apache 2.4.6 - there were some notable changes to mod_headers in 2.4.7, so maybe there was a bug specific in Apache 2.4.6 (and earlier)?